# How to dynamically add a <strong> tag with a specific class to <div> in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Below is a `div` which will be shown on a call to the javascript function `onmouseoveragent`. 
I need a name and phone number to be shown inside the div. I managed to show the name dynamically, but don't know how to add the Phone and specify its class in my function.

```
<div id="visit">
    <div id="name" class="Class1">
        <strong class="Class2">Phone: 0123456789
        </strong> <%--need this to be added dynamically--%>
    </div>
</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function onmouseoveragent(e) {

        var hint = document.getElementById("visit");
        var inner = document.getElementById("name");

        inner.appendChild(inner.ownerDocument.createTextNode("I am a name!"))      
        while (inner.childNodes.length > 1) {
            inner.removeChild(inner.firstChild);
        }

        console.log(hint);
        hint.style.display = 'block';

        hint.style.top = Math.max(el.offsetTop - hint.offsetHeight, 0) + "px";
        hint.style.left = el.offsetLeft + "px";
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('#name').append('<strong class="2">Phone: 3423423</strong>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) to create the `span` element

```
function onmouseoveragent(e) {

    var hint = document.getElementById("visit");
    var inner = document.getElementById("name");

    while (inner.childNodes.length > 0) {
        inner.removeChild(inner.firstChild);
    }
    inner.appendChild(inner.ownerDocument.createTextNode("I am a name!"))    ;

    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'Class2';
    span.innerHTML = 'Phone: 123455';
    inner.appendChild(span)

    console.log(hint);
    hint.style.display = 'block';

    hint.style.top = Math.max(el.offsetTop - hint.offsetHeight, 0) + "px";
    hint.style.left = el.offsetLeft + "px";
};
```

Comment: Many thanks, it worked perfectly fine, only it didn't apply the class to the span (because this is how I had defined the class: `.Class1 strong.Class2`.. needs a little modification) :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using innerHTML to set the contents of the 'visit' element?

Just build out in a string code exactly what you want, divs with classes, styles and everything, then just set hint.innerHTML='code'